# Can't use huawei mobile services on the new Huawei devices

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-location-kit

I'm developing an android project.I want to integrate Huawei mobile services for Huawei devices without google play services. in this project I have developed but when I test it for Huawei P40 in cloud debugging environment, Huawei mobile services don't work.It works when i test it on Huawei mate 10 pro.Huawei mobile services location kit not reacting at p40. How can i solve this please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

> I got the following message in Logcat. Message is; I/Last Location:
> Last location is null!

1. Please check whether **getLastLocation** obtains location information from the system cache. If it does, the obtained location is **null** when the system cache has been cleared. In this case, call **requestLocationUpdates** to cache the current location. Then, you can obtain the location information by calling **getLastLocation**.

Here is the HMS Core Location Kit demo on github [here](https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-location-demo-android-studio). Please update to the latest version :)

---

2. Please ensure that the location permission has been assigned to the HMS Core app. Go to **Settings** > **Apps** > **Apps** and find the HMS Core app. (The menu path may vary depending on the operating system version. If you cannot find the app, tap the menu icon in the upper right corner of **Apps** and tap **Show system processes**.) Then, tap the HMS Core icon, go to **App info** > **Permissions** > **Location**, and verify that the location permission is assigned to HMS Core.
3. You probably cannot use the high-precision location service as it is currently supported only on HUAWEI P40 series and is available only in the Chinese mainland.
4. Activity identification and geofence are not supported on emulators.
5. If the error persists, please provide us with logs of the fault.

You can perform the following operations to capture the logs:

1). Run the following command to connect to the device
`adb logcat –v time > D:\hwlocation.log`

2). Reproduce the fault.

3).Press **Ctrl+C**.

In addition, record the device model, EMUI version, HMS Core version, integrated SDK version, and fault reproduction procedure so that technical personnel can help you quickly troubleshoot the fault.

Comment: Hi shirley, thank you for your message. I did what you said but it didn't work. 
the problem still continues. I am using the codes in this link; https://github.com/busrabozdemirr/HuaweiLocationKit . When i tested it it doesn't work on huawei mate p30 pro either. So it doesn't react at all

Comment: @Motionex I will try the demo you provided. Here is the hms core location demo: https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-location-demo-android-studio

Comment: @Motionex It seems the SDK version you used is too early. Please remember replace ```implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:4.0.3.301```

Comment: I made changes to the code as you said. But it didn't work again. I got the following message in Logcat. Message is;                                                                                                   
I/Last Location: Last location is null!

Comment: By the way The demo on the link you sent is working.

Comment: @Motionex Yes, the HMS 505 version closely depends on the SDK 505 version. Your SDK version is too early. Something is wrong. You can use the official HMS Core github to download the demo.  By the way, you got ```I/Last Location: Last location is null! ``` It is because **getLastLocation** obtains location information from the system cache. The obtained location is null when the system cache has been cleared. You can check my first explanation. :)